# apply excel vba to entire column instead of single cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I would like to apply the below vba to the entire column AK instead of just AK1

```
Sub Tidy_Cell()
Range("AK1") = Replace(Range("AK1"), Chr(13), "")
For x = 1 To Len(Range("AK1"))
    If Mid(Range("AK1"), x, 1) = Chr(10) And Mid(Range("AK1"), x + 1, 1) = Chr(10) Then

    Range("AK1") = Left(Range("AK1"), x) & Mid(Range("AK1"), x + 2)

    End If
    Next
With Range("A1")
    .Value = Mid(.Value, 1)
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Try recording a macro where you select the entire column and perform this replacement (but perhaps replace "a" with "b" or something just to test).  Then see if you can use this created code to modify yours.

Answer (score 2):

I would put all your code into a Loop that checks column AK

```
dim lLastUsed As Long
lLastUsed = Cells(1048576, "AK").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 to lLastused

    //insert your code here

Next i
```

Remember every spot you defined it to be Range("AK1") you need to change it to Range("AK" & i) so it ends up something like this:

```
Sub Tidy_Cell()
Dim lLastUsed As Long
lLastUsed = Cells(1048576, "AK").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 to lLastUsed
  Range("AK" & i) = Replace(Range("AK" & i), Chr(13), "")
  For x = 1 To Len(Range("AK" & i))
    If Mid(Range("AK" & i), x, 1) = Chr(10) And Mid(Range("AK" & i), x + 1, 1) = Chr(10) Then

      Range("AK" & i) = Left(Range("AK" & i), x) & Mid(Range("AK" & i), x + 2)

    End If
  Next x
Next i

With Range("A1")
  .Value = Mid(.Value, 1)
  .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you out

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly fine